# At-the-money Call Spread approximation

Tags: options, black-scholes, spread, call

In a trading manual I got during a course, the value of the ATM Call-Spread is approximated by $CS_{ATM}=\frac{1}{2}StrD+(F-m)\times\Delta CS$
The lecturer skipped the part where he derived this approximation. And couldn't answer why this formula holds. So does anyone have a clue?
StdrD=Strike Difference, 
m= midpoint between the strikes of the call spread
F=future

$\Delta CS$ was approximated by $0.33\times\frac{StrD}{Straddle}$ (which is a consequence of the normal distribution)
Where we take straddle equal to a standard deviation (actually $\sqrt(\frac{2}{\pi})$ times would be more precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how i would explain your approximation.
First start with notation:

Define $K_{atm}$ to be the atm strike.
Define $\Delta K := K2 - K1$ where $K2 > K_{atm} > K1$. This corresponds to $\Delta K = $$StrD$ in your notation.

Now assume a black scholes world, within this world we can approximate the Call and Put price of an atm option with:
$C_{atm} = P_{atm} = 0.4 \sigma \sqrt{T} F$.Therefore the price of a straddle is given by $0.8 \sigma \sqrt{T} F$.

The delta of an option is given by $N(d1)$. For $K_{atm}$ we get that $d1 =\frac{ 0.5\sigma^2 T}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}$. So $N(d1)$ is close to 0.54. Now we evaluate $N(d1)$ at $K = K_{atm}+-straddle$. For example suppose r = 0, S = 100, T = 1, vol = 0.2 then K_{atm} = 100, the straddle = 0.8*0.2*1*100 = 16 (and a vanilla call is priced at 8). **Question:** what is the delta when evaluated at K=116 or 84? **Answer:** delta is 0.26 and 0.84. Comparing 0.26 against 0.54 and 0.84 against 0.54 we see that for the up and down **straddle move** the delta changes about **0.3**. Furthermore, by simply plotting the delta against strikes we can observe that the **delta is approximately linear** between the these strike levels.

Therefore we can explain your $\Delta CS$.
You have a move of 0.3 deltas for 1 move of size straddle. thefore a move of size $\delta K = (K_{new} - K_{atm})$ changes the delta by: $0.3 \frac{\delta K}{straddle}$. Alternatively we can write the Delta as function of K. $\Delta(K) = 0.50 + \frac{0.3(K - K_{atm})}{straddle}$

The price of a callspread is given by $C(K1) - C(K2)$. Now we approx C(K2) by:
$C(K2) = C(K1) + \int_{K1}^{K2} \Delta(K) dK$. The value of your callspread therefore is: $\int_{K1}^{K2} \Delta(K) dK$.

I think integrating the above gets you very close to the formula that you want.